# php for loop skips by twos

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a function in php that builds an html string for a table so at inside I have a for loop

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter<10; $counter++){
  $htmlString .= code for table row here;
}
```

The for loop only makes 5 rows and i even printed out the value of $counter and it says: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8

I have never seen this before and I can't think of any way to fix this other than changing the loop from 10 to 20 but I rather know what is causing this so I can fix it for good.

here is my full code for the function i pass in a row from a sql db:

```
function BuildNetworkString($Query){
        $NetworkHtml = "<table style='width:100%;'><tr>";
        $counter = 0;
        if($Query['FacebookID'] != '')
        {
            $NetworkHtml .= "<td style='width:10%; height:80px; text-align:center;'><a href='http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=" . $Query['FacebookID'] . "' class='black' title='Facebook - " . $Query['FacebookName'] . "'><img width='50px' src='Images/facebook.png'></a></td>";
            $counter+=1;
        }
        for ($counter; $counter<10; $counter++)
        {
            $NetworkHtml .= "<td style='width:10%; height:80px>&nbsp ;&nbsp;$counter</td>";
        }
        $NetworkHtml .= "</tr></table>";
        return $NetworkHtml;
    }
```

Comment: You should show us your whole code. Anyway I think you have a $counter++ inside your loop.

Comment: Your problem most likely resides in `code for table row here`.

Comment: Show the whole code in the for loop. My guess is you're incrementing `$counter` somewhere inside.

Comment: please provide more code, there is not enough here to find the problem.

Comment: and the question is ... ? If I copy your code it works as expected - obvious. Most likely (read: definitely) it has to do with your 'code for table row here', so please post that, otherwise you won't get an answer!

Comment: Just indent your code by four spaces or mark it and click the `{}` button. No need to use HTML tags for formatting. Not sure if your `&lt;` should be decoded now or not.

Comment: ya i didnt know that i updated it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
"<td style='width:10%; height:80px>&nbsp ;&nbsp;$counter</td>"
```

to:

```
"<td style='width:10%; height:80px'>&nbsp;&nbsp;$counter</td>"
```

Comment: it is like that i added the space by mistake while formatting sorry

Comment: And did you add the extra single quote after your inline style declaration?

Comment: how can i effect the counter value?

Comment: @Shaheer It doesn't affect the counter value, it just produces invalid HTML making only every other loop's HTML render in the browser. However if you view the source you can see that it doesn't actually skip any loops at all.